# How can i create 2d array with list comprehesion?

Tags: julia, list-comprehension

To make, 2d array with list comprehesion, i write this:

```
array = [f(i) for in 1:length]
```

at this, function f returns 1-d list.
But at the result as nested array....
How can i create 2d array with list comprehension?

The example of 2d dimension is like this:

```
julia> A
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0194681  0.195811  0.150168
 0.398199   0.544672  0.942663
```

Comment: can you please provide a sample of the desired results so we can try and help you with the 2 d array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `f` already returns a vector (I assume you refer to this type when you write "1-d list") then it is not possible to create a matrix using a comprehension (unless you want to write `f(i)[j]` in the example of Przemyslaw which will be inefficient).

What you should do is:

```
reduce(hcat, [f(i) for i in 1:len])
```

to get a matrix whose columns are the values returned by `f(i)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is:

```
julia> [x*y for x in 1:5, y in 1:3]
5×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1   2   3
 2   4   6
 3   6   9
 4   8  12
 5  10  15
```

Comment: With Julia 1.8, this results in a 5x3 Matrix{Int64}, not a two-dimensional array. What has changed, and why? And how do I turn this into a two-dimensional array?

Comment: `Matrix{Int64}` is an alias (short name) of  `Array{Int64,2}`. Try running in console `Matrix{Int64} === Array{Int64,2}`. It was short name in 2020 too, but simply REPL has been updated to better display matrices.